# Load multiple files, apply readChar () and function in R

Tags: xml, r, function

I have a filenames by using this

```
filenames <- list.files(getwd(), full.names=FLASE)

> filenames
[1] "2007_acura_mdx"                          "2007_acura_rdx"                          "2007_acura_rl"                          
[4] "2007_acura_tl"                           "2007_acura_tsx"                          "2007_audi_a3"                           
[7] "2007_audi_a4"                            "2007_audi_a6"                            "2007_audi_a8"                           
[10] "2007_audi_q7"                            "2007_audi_rs4"                           "2007_audi_s8"
```

And, I would like to apply

```
> for (filename in filenames) {
+     sample <- readChar(filename, file.info(filename)$size )
+ }
Error in readChar(filename, file.info(filename)$size) : 
  invalid UTF-8 input in readChar()
```

But, there is an error as you see, even though I could read one file.

```
library(XML)

xmlfilename <- "2007_acura_tl"
xmlTxt <- readChar(xmlfilename, file.info(xmlfilename)$size)

txt <- gsub(pattern ="\\&", replacement ="and", xmlTxt)

txt2 <- paste("<root>", txt, "</root>")
doc <- xmlTreeParse(txt2, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
L <- xpathApply(doc, "//DOC", xmlApply, FUN = xmlValue)
dd <- do.call(rbind, lapply(L, as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

DOCNO <- xpathApply(doc, "//DOCNO", xmlApply, FUN = xmlValue)
resultSet <- cbind(DOCNO, dd)
names(resultSet)[1]<-paste("model")
```

My final goal is

1. import all files
2. apply function in order to make a data frame from
       each xml text file

Please give some hints. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why are you using `readChar` to read in XML data? `XML`, `xml2`, `rvest` (and others) can do this for you (even possibly including the extraction and conversion to a data frame)

Comment: I am using http://kavita-ganesan.com/entity-ranking-data dataset. but, this is not real xml data format. So, I modified and processed it this way.

Comment: This is one sample data https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97ow4h4jwHcRTVtWHdudDJ0c1k/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "forgiving" mode of reading XML found in `read_html` to read in that data and make data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xml2)

doc <- read_html("OpinRankDataset/cars/2007/2007_acura_mdx")

data_frame(
  date=xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, "//doc/date")),
  author=xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, "//doc/author")),
  text=xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, "//doc/text")),
  favorite=xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, "//doc/favorite"))
) -> dat

glimpse(dat)

## Variables: 4
## $ date     (chr) "07/31/2009", "07/30/2009", "06/22/2009", "04/13/2009", "04/06/20...
## $ author   (chr) "FlewByU", "cvillemdx", "Pleased", "wasatch7", "mnozek", "Debce",...
## $ text     (chr) "I just moved to Germany two months ago and bought an 07 MDX from...
## $ favorite (chr) "The separate controls for the rear passengers are awesome. I can...
```

You can also do:

```
bind_rows(lapply(xml_find_all(doc, "//doc"),
  function(x) {
    setNames(rbind.data.frame(xml_text(xml_children(x))),  c("date", "author", "text", "favorite"))
  }))
```

if you want a less "manual labor" feel to the code, and

```
library(XML)

doc <- htmlParse("OpinRankDataset/cars/2007/2007_acura_mdx")
xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc, "//doc"))
```

if more comfortable using the XML package.

Comment: Thanks for your simple and useful code. And, I tired to get a DOCNO which is the 1st line of the XML file in order to merge with dat as a model name. xml_text(xml_find_all(doc, "//DOCNO")) But, result was empty. What is the problem? Thanks in advance again.

Comment: `xml_find_all(doc, "//docno")` with `xml2` or `xmlValue(doc[["//docno"]])` with XML.

Comment: Thanks again for your additional information. Yes, I noticed that it was changed to lower case :)

Comment: glad it helped! if this did answer your q, it helps others who do searches to tick the accept answer box (so they know this was a viable solution)